# how to cast memory of numeric types (e.g. tf.int32) to string without copy?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to hash a tensor of dtype=tf.int32 in tensorflow, but tf.keras.layers.Hashing layer convert int to string first, and then hash the string, which is time-consuming.

In C++, we can cast any memory contents to char* like this:

```
int a=1;
char* p=(char*)&a;
```

Is there any way to cast the memory of numeric types to string, or hash the memory contents directly in tensorflow?

In [tf.keras.layers.Hashing](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.11.0/keras/layers/preprocessing/hashing.py#L259)

We can see that it convert int to string first:

```
        if values.dtype.is_integer:
            values = tf.as_string(values)
        # Hash the strings.
        if self.strong_hash:
            values = tf.strings.to_hash_bucket_strong(
                values, hash_bins, name="hash", key=self.salt
            )
```

Comment: No, the cast to char * in C++ and tf.as_string do completely different things, the equivalent function would be std::to_string

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yes, tf.as_string is something like std:to_string, but my purpose is to find a quick hash funciton for numbers. Convert a number to string and hash is too slow.